# Angular2 with multiple in memory Services URL not found

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I want to expand google Tour of heroes tutorial and I want to create new modules and new in memory data services but I allways get the error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: api/trips

If you check `app/module.ts` i'm importing two in memory data services.

To get the error you can click on Heroes or Trip button

I have a working [plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/u6m8V70fWg2eZkAdje9N?p=preview)

```
InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, InMemoryTripsService),
```

Comment: This looks like an error with the implementation of your services, not with Angular. Read the error. It says "404 Not Found". This implies that you had a failed HTTP request with a status of 404. Make sure your API endpoint is accurate, and that there is a server listening for requests there.

Comment: I'm using angular in memory services, so the url should be "api/trips".I made the same implementation as HeroService

Comment: Can you try adding a forward slash to the beginning of the url?

Comment: @Lansana I got the same error: "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: /api/trips"

Comment: Do you have any access to a real API? I would advise you use that instead of playing with the fake in memory API, as you won't be able to use that in production. May as well start doing it the right way so you don't spin your wheels here.

Comment: @Lansana In memory services works if I put heroes and trips array in the same service, I was just wondering why it doesn't work with separate services.